# How to call getDefaultRowHeightByFont() function correctly in phpspreadsheet

Tags: phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am writing to excel row by row and try to get current row height after write to each row.

I tried use getDefaultRowHeightByFont() to get default row height based on font type.

```
$font_type='times new roman';
$sheet->getDefaultRowHeightByFont(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Font.$font_type)
```

The row height should be exact value that we get when manually check for row height in excel sheet. But, I got the error

```
Call to undefined method PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet::getDefaultRowHeightByFont()
```

How to call that function correctly?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to make it run.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Font as SharedFont;
$default_rowheight=SharedFont::getDefaultRowHeightByFont($spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont());
```

But, this method only show row height for default font style in that sheet. So, we could not find accurate row height for row with different font style from default.